# Adjusting composite key when deleting database elements in SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite

Consider the following table `T`

```
------------------------------
| CountryID | Obs    | Event |
------------------------------
| 1         | 1      | 10    |        
| 1         | 2      | 20    |
| 1         | 3      | 30    |
| 2         | 1      | 20    |
| 2         | 2      | 30    |
| 2         | 3      | 10    |
| 3         | 1      | 30    |
| 3         | 2      | 10    |
| 3         | 3      | 20    |
------------------------------
```

I would like to delete all rows such that `Event = 20` however I would then like to update the `Obs` so that they were still in incremental order from 1 with a difference of 1.

For example if I run `SELECT * FROM T WHERE Event != 20`, I would get

```
------------------------------
| CountryID | Obs    | Event |
------------------------------
| 1         | 1      | 10    |        
| 1         | 3      | 30    |
| 2         | 2      | 30    |
| 2         | 3      | 10    |
| 3         | 1      | 30    |
| 3         | 2      | 10    |
------------------------------
```

but instead I want

```
------------------------------
| CountryID | Obs    | Event |
------------------------------
| 1         | 1      | 10    |        
| 1         | 2      | 30    |
| 2         | 1      | 30    |
| 2         | 2      | 10    |
| 3         | 1      | 30    |
| 3         | 2      | 10    |
------------------------------
```

what query do I need to achieve this?

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) Is this really necessary?  You can calculate `Obs` when you need it rather than storing it in the database.  The best way to identify a row is through an identity/auto incrementing/serial column.

Comment: Why bother updating `Obs`? Why not just query a sequential value when you need it?

Comment: The reason I need this is because I later need a join on `T as x INNER JOIN T as y ON (x.CountryID = y.CountryID AND x.Obs = y.Obs + 1)`

Answer (score 0):

First, in SQLite, there is a pseudo-column called `rowid` that uniquely identifies each row.  You can do what you want by using a correlated subquery:

```
update t
    set obs = (select count(*)
               from t t2
               where t2.countryid = t.countryid and t2.rowid <= t.rowid
              );
```

That said, this is quite inefficient and shouldn't be run on anything other than baby tables.  If this is an operation that you regularly want to do, you might consider a more powerful database than SQLite.

Comment: Is this as efficient as the select `T as x INNER JOIN T as y ON (x.CountryID = y.CountryID AND x.Obs = y.Obs + 1)` where the `obs` are ordered as I wanted in the question. If that's the case it should be fine as that query runs quick enough on my non-baby table. I realised I could do some fairly inefficient thing using inequalities and min/max but I thought the re-ordering of the `obs` would actualy be most efficient in the long run.

Comment: @rwolst . . . Does SQLite increment the value for every match or only once in the query?  Most databases would only increment the value once.